# Join from multiple tables not returning desired data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables in my database (`contracts`, `partners` and `customers`) which a contract can be used for both customers and partners.

I only keep the contract data in `contracts` table and `customers` table and `partners` table contains a field called `contract_id` which is a foreign key to `contracts` id field.

No I want to select contracts and show them in a list, but if a contract has been used for a customer and a partner simultaneously, I want my list to show both of them, but I cant make it work.

My query is:

```
SELECT c.*, p.id AS partner_id, p.name AS partner_name, 
       cu.id AS customer_id, cu.name AS customer_name
FROM contracts AS c 
LEFT JOIN partners AS p ON c.id = p.contract_id
LEFT JOIN customers AS cu ON c.id = cu.contract_id
```

**SAMPLES:**
Records of `contract` table are like the following:

```
    id  |   title   |   contract_start  |   contract_end
-------------------------------------------------------------
    1   |   Test    |   2012-10-02      |   2013-10-02
    2   |   Test2   |   2012-09-27      |   2013-09-27
```

Records of `customers` table are like:

```
    id  |   code    |   name                |   contract_id
-------------------------------------------------------------
    1   |   123456  |   Customer1           |   1
    2   |   654321  |   Dummy Co. LTD.      |   2
```

Records of `partners` table are like:

```
    id  |   code    |   name                |   contract_id
-------------------------------------------------------------
    1   |   789456  |   Partner1            |   1
```

No I want a list with 3 records each one showing a contract (considering one of them is repeated) and each one show partner or customer name and id. If a contract is involving a customer, partner field should be `null` and vice-versa.

Comment: you have `ON c.id = cu.id`.  Shouldn't it be `ON c.id = cu.contract_id`?

Comment: @dnagirl thanks, but it doesn't affect the results :D

Comment: Since correcting the join condition doesn't fix things, perhaps you could post some sample data and the results of your query on that sample data?

Comment: This looks correct as it is. Please post a simple test case.

Comment: As I understand it, with a `LEFT JOIN` you're never going to end up with more rows in your result set than you have in the left table of the join clause. As such, you're probably seeing just the one row from the contract table, but with both partner_{id,name} and customer_{id,name} filled out for the row. Is that so?

Comment: @Justinᚅᚔᚈᚄᚒᚔ I'm sorry I couldn't describe my question better, but it's exactly as you are saying!

Comment: there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the query.  That leaves either the data or the column definitions. Try the query with only the `partners` table joined, and then only the `customers` table joined.  That will let you know which table is misbehaving.

Comment: @dnagirl I don't think there is anything wrong with my table records, The results I'm now getting are 2 records which one of them has both customer and partner data, I want each one of them in separate rows.

Comment: I usually select star on all when trouble shooting to see what is coming back. When you left (or right) join nulls will be filled in for the rows that do not match the source table on the left (or right).

Comment: @MikeCheel Thats exactly what I want, I want nulls to be returned but it's returning a row containg both customer and partner data in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say:

> No I want to select contracts and show them in a list, but if a contract has been used for a customer and a partner simultaneously, I want my list **to show both of them**

You probably need to join the two tables separately and use a `UNION`:

```
SELECT c.*, 
       p.id AS partner_id, p.name AS partner_name, 
       NULL AS customer_id, NULL AS customer_name
FROM contracts AS c 
INNER JOIN partners AS p ON c.id = p.contract_id

UNION ALL

SELECT c.*, 
       NULL AS partner_id, NULL AS partner_name, 
       cu.id AS customer_id, cu.name AS customer_name
FROM contracts AS c 
INNER JOIN customers AS cu ON c.id = cu.contract_id

UNION ALL

SELECT c.*, 
       NULL, NULL,
       NULL, NULL 
FROM contracts AS c 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *  
                   FROM partners AS p
                   WHERE c.id = p.contract_id
                 )
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                   FROM customers AS cu 
                   WHERE c.id = cu.contract_id 
                 ) ;
```

---

(Another way with different output setup)
If you prefer, you can combine the last four columns into two, adding a column to distinguish between partners and customers:

```
SELECT c.*, 
       p.id AS partner_customer_id, p.name AS partner_customer_name, 'P' AS type 
FROM contracts AS c 
INNER JOIN partners AS p ON c.id = p.contract_id

UNION ALL

SELECT c.*, 
       cu.id , cu.name, 'C'
FROM contracts AS c 
INNER JOIN customers AS cu ON c.id = cu.contract_id ;
```

Comment: I found it just a minute ago but I didn't like it because I thought I can find a better solution, are you sure that there's not any nicer, simpler solutions?

Comment: I can't think of anything simpler for this output.

Comment: I want to create a contract and to use it later! this query shows only contracts that are associated with a customer or a partner.

Comment: @faridv: In your question, you say you want to retrieve 3 rows (given your sample data), with duplicates of contract 1, and with either the customer fields or the partner fields as NULL on each duplicate. That is exactly what the first query in this answer does. So, do you want only associated contracts like you say in your question, or do you want non-associated contracts?

Comment: @Justinᚅᚔᚈᚄᚒᚔ When I was writing the question, I was only thinking about associated contracts, but when I found this solution and used it, I realized that it's the contracts that are being created first and then customers or partners are being assigned to them. So I create a contract but I cannot see it until I associate a customer or partner to it! So now I want both associated contracts and non-associated contracts in one list. Of course if it's possible!